# Notepad++ How to remove last character (:) on every line

Tags: regex, replace, notepad++

In Notepad++ how can I remove `:` at the end of lines like this

> FRUIT:SHOP:TBA0002:RACK 01:LINE 1:TOP:MAX:1602:1612:

So it will become like this

> FRUIT:SHOP:TBA0002:RACK 01:LINE 1:TOP:MAX:1602:1612

I have a very large list which consists of around 3000 lines.

Comment: copy to Excel and use left function to exclude the last character.. then copy back to notepad...

Comment: I've done something similar with notepad++ before. But just use the find and replace. Look for ":\n" and replace with "\n" or something like that. You may need to mess with the find and replace options.

Answer (score 43):

You can use a regular expression at the replace dialog.

Find:

```
.{1}$
```

Replace with nothing
then just select `Replace All`

Full options are:

[image]

Comment: This removes the last character, not a trailing :

Comment: Yes, you're right. But in this case the (:) are at the end of the lines, so it solves his problem.

Answer (score 21):

From the manual [Regular Expressions](https://npp-user-manual.org/docs/searching/#regular-expressions) page, it states

> Notepad++ regular expressions use the Boost regular expression library v1.70, which is based on PCRE (Perl Compatible Regular Expression) syntax

So, you must simply search for a regular expression

```
:$
```

and replace this with nothing.

The dollar sign `$` denotes the end of line.

For more on regular expressions, see the Notepad++ manual link above or http://www.regular-expressions.info/.

Answer (score 7):

Use find and replace, check the extended option, look for `:\r\n` and replace with `\r\n`. This will remove them all except for the last line.

Comment: It works only on windows file when line break is CRLF, but not on other platforms.

Comment: Correct! \r\n works on Windows, but the way Linux or other OSs are organized - you will need to use them in another sequence or characters. For example(I am not sure, a friend had mentioned it once) for Linux it works if it is spelled backwards - \n\r. I believe this is easy to check for those who are interested, not just for Linux, but other OS too.